# IK Solver Chain Length reverts back to 0 when changing between pose and object mode

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

So I've been working on rigging a model for animation and I've set up IK chain links between a few different body parts.

For some reason, the left leg of my character model won't maintain it's IK settings. Specifically, "Chain Length", which I set to 2, keeps reverting back to 0, causing my model to act in a variety of weird ways.

I have even gone as far as to delete the IK chain completely, and start again, but the issue continued.

I have also saved and closed the .blend whilst the issue was no present, but after reloading it, the issue came back very shortly.

This is seriously slowing down progress and if anyone has a solution to this issue I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I noticed that I had (probably accidentally) inserted a keyframe by clicking this small dot button right next to the > arrow key which changed into a diamond shape. After clicking it again it removed the keyframe, turned back to a dot and the changed number was saved just fine

[image]

Another indication is that the Chain Length field was yellow / orange, instead of the regular grey, while that diamond icon was around.

[image]